# Loose images in uploads folder

Tags: images, uploads, library

thanks for viewing. The uploads folder of this site has hundreds of loose images after someone turned off the folder structure for a year. These images are being used in older posts so not ideal just to delete them. Is there any way of running a query that would identify upload date and move images into their date folder? Then theres the problem of broken image links in the posts. Any way of automatically remapping them? Long shot but just putting it out there!

Thank you!